# when I pop the view B to A my A views textfield data shows empty.View A is root view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fname_txt.delegate=self;
    self.lname_txt.delegate=self;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString* textField1Text = fname_txt.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:k_firstname];

    NSString* textField2Text = lname_txt.text;
    [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:k_lastname];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: i have multiple Viws...A,B,C,D ....In view A i Have textfields....when i type in that textfield and goes to ViewB and done some operation when i pop up back then my textfield text in View A show empty...plz help me

Comment: you mean data in userdefaults empty or text in textfields are empty which one??

Comment: i type text in textfield and when i pop the view textfield show empty

Comment: assign text to the textfields from defaults in we will appear method in A view. It may works

Comment: i didnt usderstand plz explain i code

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

self.fname_txt=[defaults valueforKey:k_firstname];
self.lname_txt=[defaults valueforKey:k_lastname];
}
```

This method calls every time so ucan handle this method as per your requirement by using bool value r anything.